# Can't build Visual Studio 2022 solution or run in container on Windows Server, error 125, Blazor, .NET 7

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio, blazor

I'm trying to Dockerize a Blazor web app in Visual Studio 2022 with .NET 7 on a Windows Server, and I get a build error:

> CTC1015 Docker command failed with exit code 125.

The output from container tools is this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: flow3webapp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Skipping analyzers to speed up the build. You can execute 'Build' or 'Rebuild' command to run analyzers.
1>FLOW3WebApp -> C:\code\FLOW\FLOWCSharp\FLOW3WebApp\bin\Debug\net7.0\FLOW3WebApp.dll
1>docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\*********\onecoremsvsmon\17.7.10830.2695:C:\remote_debugger:ro" -v "C:\Users\*********\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\OITLASALLEGS0\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro" -v "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\tools\TokenService.Proxy\win10-x64\net7.0:C:\TokenService.Proxy:ro" -v "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\tools\HotReloadProxy\win10-x64\net7.0:C:\HotReloadProxy:ro" -v "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\HotReload:C:\HotReloadAgent:ro" -v "C:\code\FLOW\FLOWCSharp\FLOW3WebApp:C:\app" -v "C:\code\FLOW\FLOWCSharp\FLOW3WebApp:c:\src" -v "C:\Users\**********.nuget\packages\:c:\.nuget\fallbackpackages" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=c:\.nuget\fallbackpackages" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=c:\.nuget\fallbackpackages" -P --name FLOW3WebApp_1 --entrypoint C:\remote_debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe flow3webapp:dev /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn /nowowwarn /fallbackloadremotemanagedpdbs /timeout:2147483646 /LogDebuggeeOutputToStdOut
1>c61631fa1c93688583fb6b687da07e753fc5eae722e00f87793ffebf8c0dd109
1>docker: Error response from daemon: container c61631fa1c93688583fb6b687da07e753fc5eae722e00f87793ffebf8c0dd109 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: Access is denied. (0x5).
1>docker rm -f c61631fa1c93688583fb6b687da07e753fc5eae722e00f87793ffebf8c0dd109
1>c61631fa1c93688583fb6b687da07e753fc5eae722e00f87793ffebf8c0dd109
1>C:\Users\***************\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.19.4\build\Container.targets(213,5): error CTC1015: Docker command failed with exit code 125.
1>C:\Users\***********\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.19.4\build\Container.targets(213,5): error CTC1015: docker: Error response from daemon: container c61631fa1c93688583fb6b687da07e753fc5eae722e00f87793ffebf8c0dd109 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: Access is denied. (0x5).
1>C:\Users\**********\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.19.4\build\Container.targets(213,5): error CTC1015: If the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop.
1>Done building project "flow3webapp.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 10:52 AM and took 15.110 seconds ==========
```

Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FLOW3WebApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./FLOW3WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "FLOW3WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FLOW3WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FLOW3WebApp.dll"]
```

When I first right clicked add----> docker support in VS I tried linux, but when I ran it said that docker was configured for windows, so I blew away that docker file and followed the visual studio prompts to make the dockerfile for Windows.

So basically I'm trying to just run this when I select the docker option at the top of visual studio in the debug section.  One time I added Administrator in the top portion of the docker file and I got it run from a cli but it was then asking for admin credentials in a popup.  So I started over and now I'm getting error 125 and these no access errors.

I tried installing docker desktop but when installing it said it's not compatible with the OS for windows server, so the only docker I have is in the program files/docker etc.....And I'm pretty sure the docker daemon is running as a service, I've also restarted the daemon a couple of times to see if that helped, but no dice.

I don't know what to do, if I add administrator in the dockerfile it asks for credentials that I don't have, and the web app is not asking for any log in credentials.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which version of Windows Server are you using?

Comment: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, and docker 20.10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing the access issue you're seeing is probably that you're running as an administrator on the host and the user in the container doesn't have access to the volume mounted files.

**Option 1:**
You can run as an admin in the conatainer. You need to change you docker file to include:

```
USER ContainerAdministrator
```

in the base stage. When running as `ContainerAdministrator` you'll also need extra volumes to use the SSL cert generated by VS. To do that add

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DockerfileRunArguments> -v "$(APPDATA)\Microsoft\UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro" -v "$(APPDATA)\ASP.NET\Https:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro"</DockerfileRunArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

To your project file.

**Option 1.5:**
Rather than changing your Dockerfile to set the user you can modify the Docker run command, which is nice as it won't alter the production image. To do that add:

```
<!-- Including the volume mounts from above in case you're using HTTPS -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <DockerfileRunArguments> -v "$(APPDATA)\Microsoft\UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro" -v "$(APPDATA)\ASP.NET\Https:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro" --user ContainerAdministrator</DockerfileRunArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

To your project file.

**Option 2:**
You can view the docker run command in the container tools or build panes of the output window. If you check all of the volume mounts (passed with -v) you may be able to get this working by giving access to those folders to a built-in group like Everyone (but this is unwise)

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks, I got the build to work and the container to run with option 1.5 you listed above, I deleted and refreshed the ssl certificates, but for some reason my system wants smart card authorization at a javascript prompt when the app starts in the browser for https and http.  It's a government system.  :-(  Saying there's a problem with a smart card driver.    I can't imagine that the end users will have to enter their smart card credentials when they use the app, if they have any.

Comment: I didn't see this in my testing, so I assume this is something in the app you're running.

Comment: I accepted your answer Nathan as your steps allowed me to build.  When i fix the auth problem I'll post the solution.