# Chrome and Edge keep asking for browser authentication when running Blazor 7.0 app with Docker in Windows Datacenter

Tags: docker, visual-studio, blazor

I have a blazor web app, when I hit the docker play button on the toolbar in visual studio 2022 chrome and edge keep popping up a browser prompt for username and password.  This doesn't happen when I run with the http option, https option or IIS option in the visual studio toolbar.  The operating system I'm running on is Windows 2019 Datacenter.

*Sorry, I keep trying to post images of chrome and edge asking for credentials but it's not showing here.

Chrome asks for user/password and edge starts by asking for user/pass and then asks for my smartcard credentials.

When I click the docker play button it launches edge with this
url https://localhost:56441/, I also manually put in http://localhost:56442/ to try http but still wants browser authentication.

The container outputs/ports tab shows
container port 80 host port 56442 and
container port 443 host port 56441

Here is the container log VS output

```
 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepositor
y[60]
      Storing keys in a directory 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local
\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container
. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14] 
      Now listening on: https://[::]:443 
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]     
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80   
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Originally I couldn't even get the project to build but if you reference this stackoverflow post you can see the dockerfile and some other info that might help

[Can't build Visual Studio 2022 solution or run in container on Windows Server, error 125, Blazor, .NET 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531595/cant-build-visual-studio-2022-solution-or-run-in-container-on-windows-server-e)

Here is my dockerfile generated by visual studio

```
#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FLOW3WebApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./FLOW3WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "FLOW3WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FLOW3WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FLOW3WebApp.dll"]
```

Here is my project file that I modified according the stackoverflow link I posted above.

```
Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>d56b1527-83d0-438c-bf1c-7371d252284c</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazor.WebForm.Components" Version="2.3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazor.WebForm.UI" Version="2.3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" Version="10.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Collections" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- Including the volume mounts from above in case you're using HTTPS -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DockerfileRunArguments> -v "$(APPDATA)\Microsoft\UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro" -v "$(APPDATA)\ASP.NET\Https:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro" --user ContainerAdministrator</DockerfileRunArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I am now going to try to install WSL 2 on the system and see if that changes anything, other than that I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what to do.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit:  Perhaps my entire docker configuration is screwed from the start because it's configured to run on Windows I believe and I'm of the understanding docker containers won't run on Windows without docker desktop, however 2019 datacenter isn't compatible with docker desktop.  I'm going to see if someone responds, but I'll blow away my current dockerfile and change back the csproj file in the morning and see what happens.  I believe I tried I did this for linux when I added docker support to vs but I think something went wrong.