# How can I modify my docker configuration/.dockerfile to work with windows authentication in and asp.net 7 blazor app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, blazor

I am trying to containerize an asp.net version 7 app on windows datacenter. Docker desktop doesn't run on the os so I am doing all the docker commands in the cli. It is a docker linux container.  When I run the container and expose a port the web app will prompt me with a browser based user/pass.  The blazor app needs to use windows authentication.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

When I comment out the AddAuthentication and AddAuthorization methods my containerized app will be served up without prompting for browswer authentication user/pass which is good, however the database connection will immediately fail because it needs the windows user.

I think I need to modify the dockerfile, but I have no idea what to put in there for this.

My current dockerfile is this....

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FLOW3WebApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./FLOW3WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "FLOW3WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FLOW3WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FLOW3WebApp.dll"]
```

Here is a related post that died on the vine. [Chrome and Edge keep asking for browser authentication when running Blazor 7.0 app with Docker in Windows Datacenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77597140/chrome-and-edge-keep-asking-for-browser-authentication-when-running-blazor-7-0-a)   Any help is appreciated.